# Загрузка фото cURL

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, post, curl

Доброго времени суток !

Стоит такая задача, загрузить фото в альбом ВК.

Вот рабочий код, всё работает:

```
$image_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/111.png';
$post_data = array("file1" => '@'.$image_path);

$url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getUploadServer?album_id=".$album_id."&group_id=".$group_id."&v=".$v."&access_token=".$token);
$url = json_decode($url)->response->upload_url;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
$request_params_savePhoto = array
(
    'album_id' => $result['aid'],
    'group_id' => $group_id,
    'server' => $result['server'],
    'photos_list' => $result['photos_list'],
    'hash' => $result['hash'],
    'v' => '5.69',
    'access_token'=> $token
);
$get_params_savePhoto = http_build_query($request_params_savePhoto);
$resultUpload = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.save?'. $get_params_savePhoto),true);
print_r($resultUpload);
```

Я хочу загрузить фото которое отправлено через POST форму не сохраняя его у себя на сервере, как такое реализовать ? 

Пробовал таким образом, Не получается.

```
$image_path = $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Не думаю что это возможно с CURL.. А что вам мешает сохранять файл во временную директорию?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, а как сохранять во временную директорию и потом удалять ?

Comment: Ищущие да взыщут (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php ). А удалять как обычный файл. Всё связанное со временными файлами и директориями там, в этой ссылке.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Как реализовать загрузку фото через `POST` запрос, не сохраняя фото у себя на сервере ?

---

8 Дней плутав по интернету в поисках ответа на этот вопрос, я все таки нашел ответ !

Для того чтобы реализовать загрузку через `cURL` нужен `PHP` не ниже `5.5`.

Так как формат `@` устарел в `PHP 5.5` добавили функцию `curl_file_create()`.

Вот код:

```
    $tmpfile = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $filemime = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
    $post_data = array(
        'file1' => curl_file_create($tmpfile, $filemime, basename($filename))
    );
```

---

Источник этого драгоценного ответа [вот*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223977/send-file-via-curl-from-form-post-in-php/29122849#29122849)